# Prop manipulation of adjacent elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a layered menu, I have something like this:

```
<a onclick={this.handleClick()}>Nav Link</a>
<div open={false}>
    Hidden Submenu
</div>
```

In my `handleClick` function, I want to be able to toggle the prop of the submenu *adjacent* to the link clicked, and toggle it from false to true and vice versa every time it's clicked.

In summary, I want the React version of this jQuery thing:`$("a").next().prop("open", "true")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintain state for your `open` variable,

```
state = {open:false}
```

//handleClick to toggle

```
handleClick = () => {
   this.setState({open: !this.state.open})
}
```

While in `onClick` neven call function like this `this.handleClick()` <== `() not needed`

```
<a onclick={this.handleClick}>Nav Link</a>
<div open={this.state.open}>
    Hidden Submenu
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the property which triggers the prop of the submenu in the state per example:

```
state = {
isSubmenuShowing: false
}
```

The div will look like this:

```
<div open={this.state.isSubmenuShowing}>
...
</div>
```

Then on handleClick change it

```
handleClick(){
this.setState({isSubmenuShowing: !this.state.isSubmenuShowing});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have state you can't change props directly in react.You can do it with class component but i prefer using functional component with hooks like this:

```
import React from "react"
    const collapse = ()=>{
        const [open,setopen]=React.useState(false)

        return(
        <a onClick={()=>setopen(!open)}>Nav Link</a>
        <div open={false}>
            Hidden Submenu
        </div>
        )

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple JavaScript Code

```
  var counter=0;
  function handleClick(){
   counter=++counter; // Adds 1 onClick

if(counter===1){

prop1(); //Executes prop 1 when counter is 1

}else if(counter===2){

prop2(); // Prop 2 when counter is 2
counter=0; // Counter returned to 0 so that this toggle can be used again

}

   }
```

Comment: OP need to do this in React.